# How to create Form from Json schema and Ui schema in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin

How to create Form from Json schema and Ui schema in Android Kotlin? I am new to mobile development and am a little bit confused how to do this in Jetpack Compose app. I find many ways to create a form in React. For Android Kotlin there is https://github.com/ellykits/neat-form , but it requires a different schema structure of Json schema. I have Json schema as below:

```
{
  "title": ".....",
  "description": "",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "description",
    "violationType"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "videoLink": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Видео",
      "default": "https://....."
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "....."
    },
    "violationType": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": ".......?",
      "enum": [
        ".....",
        ".....",
        ".....",
        ".....",
        "....."
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and Ui schema:

```
{
  "description": {
    "ui:widget":"textarea"
  },
  "violationType": {
    "ui:widget":"radio"
  },
  "videoLink": {
    "ui:widget": "customVideoWidget"
  },
  "ui:order": [
    "videoLink",
    "description",
    "violationType"
  ]
}
```

And could you advice me what can I read to understand how to work with Json schema to create forms?

Thank you very much for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done by creating a **factory** class and pass form item and it will decide with **FormItemView** to return.

**FormItemView** is a view extending for example **MaterialTextInput** and sets input type and placeholder, etc that it gets from json.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try